# How can I set the value of two $scope variables based on the value of one?

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with two fields:

```
<input data-ng-model="pidLower" />
<input data-ng-model="pidUpper" />
```

I would like to replace this with one field that has some intelligence:

```
<input data-ng-model="pid" />
```

So that entering:

- "1" would set $scope.pidLower to be 1
- "100" would set $scop.pidLower to be 100
- "1 - 2" would set $scope.pidLower to be 1 and $scope.pidUpper to be 2
- "- 99"  would set $scope.pidUpper to be 99

Can anyone suggest a way that I could do this in my controller? I am not sure if
I would need to put this in a watch or if it could be done with some function.

Background:

Here's where I am using pidLower and pidUpper:

```
$scope.isProblemInRange = function (row) {
                return (row.problemId >= $scope.pidLower || $scope.pidLower == null || $scope.pidLower == "") &&
                       (row.problemId < $scope.pidUpper || $scope.pidUpper == null || $scope.pidUpper == "")
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch it and decide:

```
$scope.$watch("pid", function(pid) {
    if( pid == null || pid === "" ) {
        $scope.pidLower = null;
        $scope.pidUpper = null;
    }
    else if( pid.indexOf("-") > 0 ) {
        pid = pid.split("-");
        $scope.pidLower = parseInt(pid[0]);
        $scope.pidUpper = parseInt(pid[1]);
    }
    else {
        $scope.pidLower = parseInt(pid);
    }
});
```

*BE WARNED:* This is only example code, it will work roughly, but your exact use case may require some modifications. It is the `$watch` principle I am trying to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks - I will try this out shortly :-)